# CoreData: query with NONE

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I Have the following model:

[image]

I need to get all PT objects WHERE **none** of hasStatus objects belongs to groupId = 4. So, **none** of PTStatus object property status.group.groupId = 4.

I've tried several ways, but it's returning PTs that have some PTSTatus where groupId = 4.

For example:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PT" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE hasStatus.status.group.groupId == %@",
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
```

Any help?

Comment: Show the options you have tried. Was one a subquery?

Comment: @Wain inserted example

Comment: Is the groupid a number or a string? You could try something like 
SUBQUERY(hasStatus, $b, ANY $b.status.group.groupid = '4').@count = 0

Comment: @Wain it crashes when connected to FetchResultController with the following error: The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.

Comment: query: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(hasStatus, $b, ANY $b.status.group.groupId = %@).@count == 0",
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:4]
                                 ];

Comment: Because we're already inside the to-many. In what way does your original return too many results? Does it return everything?

Comment: @Wain If a PT has many status, where at least one belongs to groupId 4, in my old NSPredicate, it would return that PT. What I don't want too. Applying your SUBQUERY, it works, but connected to a NSFetchRequestController, it crashes with that message.

Comment: Not sure why the crash at the moment, but an FRC wouldn't help you as it doesn't monitor associated objects - you would need another mechanism to refetch and update your results...